# MATLAB organise external toolboxes or turn them into packages to prevent shadowing

Tags: matlab, package

I'm working on a large data analysis that incorporates lots of different elements and hence I make heavy use of external toolboxes and functions from file exchange and github. Adding them all to the path via startup.m is my current working method but I'm running into problems of shadowing function names across toolboxes. I don't want to manually change function names or turn them into packages, since a) it's a lot of work to check for shadowing and find all function calls and more importantly b) I'm often updating the toolboxes via git. Since I'm not the author all my changes would be lost.
Is there programmatic way of packaging the toolboxes to create their own namespaces? (With as little overhead as possible?)
Thanks for the help

Comment: You might want to check this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html

Comment: @CST-Link: That would require touching the code, any reference to another function / class in the same package has to be changed to `packagename.classname`

Comment: I think the easiest way to deal with it is to `addpath` the toolbox you use in each script\function up in the path list, so the correct one is used (Matlab gives priority to path which is higher in the list). I faced a similar situation, and from my experience this is the clearest way, because you see explicitly in each m file what toolbox is meant to be used.

Comment: @Daniel Not necessarily. Instead of fully qualifying all the internal-kitchen function calls, one may start the function with `import <package>.*` to avoid headaches. Besides, proper toolboxes are already organized as packages, so fully qualified names should work. That would require changing the "client" code only.

Comment: I assumed qa asks for a solution without any code modification. Accepting minimal modifications this is the best solution. I suggest to write an answer.

Comment: @CST-Link: It's nice to think that all proper toolboxes should be organized as packages while a lot of them are older than the package feature and haven't been reorganized. I organize my own toolboxes as packages, yes, but most of the external ones are still just folders and subfolders. With your approach I would need to add import <package>.* to all direct accessible functions, which are still more than a couple of hundred files. And I would need to repeat this with every pull. Is there no better way to organize them?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this. Basic idea is to make all functions in a private folder and have only one entry point visible. This entry point is the only file seeing the toolbox, and at the same time it sees the toolbox function first regardless of the order in the search path.

toolbox/exampleToolbox.m

```
function varargout=exampleToolbox(fcn,varargin)
fcn=str2func(fcn);
varargout=cell(1,nargout);
[varargout{:}]=fcn(varargin{:});
end
```

with toolbox/exampleToolbox/private/foo.m beeing an example function.

Now you can call `foo(1,2,3)` via `exampleToolbox('foo',1,2,3)`

The same technique could be used generating a class. This way you could use `exampleToolbox.foo(1,2,3)`

Comment: The problem with this is I need to change the folder structure, which is given by the authors. If I want to go this route I could just create a +packageFolder and dump all the functions in there. But this won't allow me to see changes across repositories easily to watch for meaningful updates. And I would still need to move all files after each pull. Also because Matlab doesn't allow subfolders in private folders.

Comment: Why not have your repo directly in the "private" folder? I don't see any reason to move.

Comment: The repos have their own organization in folders, but Matlab does not support subfolders in private folders, i.e. all function files have to lie directly in the private folder. If I just put my external repo in the private folder everything that is one folder down will be unknown to matlab and to your helper function.

Comment: You are right, forgot about private in private. With that in mind and assuming a toolbox has more than one folder with code in it, I do not have a solution.